# Default privileges granted only if table created by one superuser

Tags: postgresql, users

I have a role group called `normal_users`, my username is `rbourgeon` (I am superuser) and there is another superuser called `admin`.

I previously ran the following query:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA myschema GRANT ALL ON TABLES TO normal_users;
```

Now, if I am logged in as `rbourgeon` and create a new table in the schema, I can see the privilege `normal_users=arwdDxt`, which is the expected behaviour.

But now, the strange thing is, if I log in as `admin` and create another table in the same schema, the role `normal_users` will **not** be granted these privileges on this table.

The [official PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html), on this issue, reads:

> ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES allows you to set the privileges that will be
>   applied to objects created in the future. (It does not affect
>   privileges assigned to already-existing objects.) Currently, only the
>   privileges for tables (including views), sequences, and functions can
>   be altered.
>
> **You can change default privileges only for objects that will be
>   created by yourself or by roles that you are a member of.** The
>   privileges can be set globally (i.e., for all objects created in the
>   current database), or just for objects created in specified schemas.
>   Default privileges that are specified per-schema are added to whatever
>   the global default privileges are for the particular object type.

Is there a workaround? Because many users may create tables in this database.